# Apache ignite wrong IPs are discovered

Tags: java, spring, docker, ignite, testcontainers

I run Apache Ignite instance in test container like shown below:

```
GenericContainer<?> apacheIgniteContainer =new GenericContainer<>("apacheignite/ignite")
                .withExposedPorts(10800, 47100, 47500);

            apacheIgniteContainer.setPortBindings(Arrays.asList("10800:10800", "47100:47100", "47500:47500"));
            apacheIgniteContainer.start();
```

and this is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public Ignite igniteInstance() {
    return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration());
}

    private IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();

    igniteConfiguration.setFailureDetectionTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi());
    igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false);
    igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration());
    igniteConfiguration.setLocalHost(LOCALHOST);

    TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    communicationSpi.setLocalAddress(LOCALHOST);

    igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);

    return igniteConfiguration;
}

private TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder() {
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder(true);
    tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.setAddresses((Arrays.asList(LOCALHOST)));

    return tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder;
}

private TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi() {
    TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder());
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalAddress(LOCALHOST);
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(10800);

    return tcpDiscoverySpi;
}

private CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration("exampleCache");
    cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Example.class);

    return cacheConfiguration;
}
```

And the problem is that I pass only LOCALHOST to discover/communications services but every time integration test starts wrong IP addresses are registered. Here are logs:

```
07:20:21.376 [exchange-worker-#48] WARN  [] o.a.i.s.c.t.TcpCommunicationSpi - Connect timed out (consider increasing 'failureDetectionTimeout' configuration property) [addr=/172.17.0.5:47100, failureDetectionTimeout=30000]
07:20:40.267 [main] WARN  [] o.a.i.i.p.c.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Still waiting for initial partition map exchange [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3ad0b9b8-6f30-4e77-9874-e766dd266f15, addrs=[127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=2, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1580970000048, loc=true, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=true], topVer=2, nodeId8=3ad0b9b8, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1580970000227], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ae6dd269-fbb8-413e-ad2e-7ed9e2ae2495, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.5], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.5:47500, 624f07442eab/52.18.154.42:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1580970000164, loc=false, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3ad0b9b8-6f30-4e77-9874-e766dd266f15, addrs=[127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=2, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1580970000048, loc=true, ver=2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=true], topVer=2, nodeId8=3ad0b9b8, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1580970000227], nodeId=3ad0b9b8, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=337147080], init=false, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=null, stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1580970000258, centralizedAff=false, forceAffReassignment=false, exchangeLocE=null, cacheChangeFailureMsgSent=false, done=false, state=CLIENT, registerCachesFuture=null, partitionsSent=false, partitionsReceived=false, delayedLatestMsg=null, afterLsnrCompleteFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=441482912], evtLatch=0, remaining=[ae6dd269-fbb8-413e-ad2e-7ed9e2ae2495], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=114452799]]]
```

...

```
07:20:42.396 [exchange-worker-#48] WARN  [] o.a.i.s.c.t.TcpCommunicationSpi - Connect timed out (consider increasing 'failureDetectionTimeout' configuration property) [addr=624f07442eab/52.18.154.42:47100, failureDetectionTimeout=30000]
07:20:42.430 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#32] INFO  [] o.a.i.s.c.t.TcpCommunicationSpi - Established outgoing communication connection [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:59666, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100]
```

So at first it tries to connect with: 172.17.0.5:47100 (I have no idea where this address is from) and it fails. After this it tries to connect to proper IP (localhost) and then test passes. So my question is why it tries to connect to first IP (172.17.0.5:47100) - i didn't even specified it.

Comment: Did you solve the issue finally?

Answer (score 1):

Every node binds to the following two ports:

- Discovery (47500 by default)
- Communication (47100 by default)

Also in your case it seems that you decided to expose a JDBC/ODBC/Thin clients port, which is 10800.

If you want to work using localhost interface, you need to specify it in **both** discovery and communication.
So, you need to add something like this to your configuration:

```
TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
communicationSpi.setLocalAddress(LOCALHOST);

igniteCfg.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);
```

Also, I have the following two concerns about your discovery SPI configuration:

1. DiscoverySPI tries to connect to port 10800. This is a port for JDBC. It should be matching the ports other nodes' discovery bind to (47500 by default).
2. You use multicast IP finder. It can make your node connect to unexpected nodes. Consider using a static IP finder.

You can find more in the documentation: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added TcpCommunicationSpi like you suggested, but it behaves the same - still got error while trying to connect to 172.17.0.5:47100. Secondly I edited my config class - in fact I use TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder which is static IP finder. So I assume TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder will try to connect only to addresses I pass in setAddresses() method but in fact it doesn't. No idea why.

Comment: Could you add the fixed configuration to the question?

Comment: What is the value of `LOCALHOST`?

Comment: Denis - yes I have already done that - I only removed 3 three lines which weren't used anyway. Also: `String LOCALHOST = "localhost";`

Comment: I still don't see the communication SPI configuration. Could you add it?

Comment: Ok, my bad. I added communicationSPI in my code but not in question. Now I updated both.

Comment: I also recommend removing the following line: `tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(10800); ` since it's using the port 10800 in a wrong way.
Did the error messages change at all, or they just stayed exactly the same?

Comment: Denis - everything stayed exactly the same.

Comment: Could you share your full logs somewhere (pastebin maybe)? Did you try removing setting the discovery port?

Comment: Yes I removed discovery port - no result. Look at logs please:

https://pastebin.com/7MHbDnJs

Comment: @MichałProkop I can only see logs of client nodes (they have `clientMode=true` in `IgniteConfiguration`). Could you also provide logs from the server node? It seems to be the only node with IP=172.17.0.5.

Comment: By the way I can see that you use java 13 to run the client node. I'm not sure that 13th java is supported in the `Ignite` 2.7.6. And it differs from the java used on a server node (it's 8th).

Comment: @Denis Yes, it may help, look please:

https://pastebin.com/4dLfXYqK

Comment: It doesn't seem that the configuration is actually applied. The node uses 0.0.0.0 as a local host and `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` as an IP finder. Make sure that a proper configuration is used.